# Creating an XmlNode programatically in XmlDocument style issue

Tags: c#, .net, xml, forms

I'm having trouble getting the Xml output to file that I expect.

I want this:

`<Book id="RED" desc="All about the color." mmtype="NO">`

`</Book>`

But what I get is this:

`<Book id="RED" desc="All about the color." mmtype="NO" />`

My code for creating the node is:

```
XmlNode newNode = _xmlDocument.CreateElement("Book");
//Add Attributes
XmlAttribute attrID = _xmlDocument.CreateAttribute("id");
attrID.Value = newBook.ID;
newNode.Attributes.Append(attrID);

XmlAttribute attrDesc = this._xmlDocument.CreateAttribute("desc");
attrDesc.Value = newBook.Description;
newNode.Attributes.Append(attrDesc);

XmlAttribute attrMmType = this._xmlDocument.CreateAttribute("mmtype");
attrMmType.Value = newBook.mmType;
newNode.Attributes.Append(attrMmType);

//Add new child node to parent
parentNode.InsertBefore(newNode, parentNode.FirstChild);
```

I don't see how to setup the node differently to get the block outcome.
Perhaps I need to add a child to the node before saving it? But I don't have any
for this particular node.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need it to look like that when you don't have child nodes? Just genuinely curious.

Comment: I guess it's just to mirror past xml file usage. I'm editing existing xml files and wanted it to look the same. Looking back through existing files I see there are no nodes without children. So I guess I need to look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<Tag />` is the shortform of `<Tag></Tag>` Where there's nothing inbetween the open/close portions.

You may be able to get around this by adding a `XmlText` with whitespace as a child of the element but realize this really is pointless in the long run as you're just formatting it visually in a non-optimal way. Any decent XML Parser should be able to read short form tags as it's the recommended behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Aren, I understand that its a perfectly accepted form of tag, just wondered if I was doing something wrong with the code. It looks like its just the difference between having and not having children. Your answer was spot on.